# Macbook Pro 13 in, 16GB Ram, i7 3.1, 512 GB Flash Storage Purchase

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, memory, mac-pro

I recently purchased the Macbook Pro 13 in (Early 2015) model, with specs in the title. I was wondering if this is good purchase for a power user who does software engineering, UI / UX Design, database creation, etc.

I have been previously using a Q200E Asus Laptop with a modified SSD/HD harddisk but found that the laptop was too slow at times and that was really cutting into my dev time.

Is this a good buy? Will this keep me good for the next couple of years? I am looking at this as a long term investment.

Users who currently have these specs how is it?

I will also say another factor in me buying a Macbook Pro was to start development for iPhone applications.

Comment: You already purchased the MBP, so why not just give it a try yourself?

Comment: It hasn't arrived yet and I have a 2 week window to return it

Comment: [MacPerformanceguide.com](http://macperformanceguide.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be an Apple cool-aid drinker, but the answer is still yes.

I code for a living on a PC but have never personally owned a PC. I am deeply engrained in the Mac experience and every day at work I miss the subtle, simple, and elegant nuances of MAC OS. I've cussed Windows about some *thing* every day for 14 consecutive years.

My Mac experience from a user perspective is that Mac hardware has longer useful life. My average is about 7 years. We'll see as the Mac becomes less upgradable.

2008 iMac(Core 2 Duo, 6GB RAM): OS upgraded 4 times now, starting w/ OS X 10.5 now running Mavericks (OS X 10.9.5) just fine. It will run Yosemite.  RAM upgraded beyond the official maximum RAM supported. My 2nd Mac I've done that with. Windows 7 emulation is satisfactory, but only after I upgraded from 4 to 6GB of RAM.

2012 MacBook Pro (i7, 8GB RAM): Replaced original hard drive w/ an SSD, moved that drive to the CD bay, put the CD player in an external enclosure. OS X upgraded twice, running Mavericks just fine. This thing cold boots to Parallels -> Win 7 -> visual studio faster than my PC at work. Much faster. I have no performance issues.

P.S. I hope your SSD is 6G SATA, and not 3.

2009 iPhone 3GS: Cannot upgrade to iOS 7, but still syncs (via iTunes) with Mac running Mavericks.

Last "code camp" I went to *every* presenter doing web or Visual Studio specifically were all using MacBook Pros. One told me "I wish I'd done it sooner." I use Parallels to drive Windows 7, and parallels integration of the Mac/Windoze Frankenstein is astonishing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful im looking forward to the Linux Based OSX system!